# R: Resampling By Group

Tags: r

I am working with the R programing language.

I have the following data on a set of students repeatedly flipping a (potentially correlated/biased) coin a different numbers of time:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)
ids <- 1:100
student_id <- sort(sample(ids, 100000, replace = TRUE))
coin_result <- character(1000)
coin_result[1] <- sample(c("H", "T"), 1)

for (i in 2:length(coin_result)) {
  if (student_id[i] != student_id[i-1]) {
    coin_result[i] <- sample(c("H", "T"), 1)
  } else if (coin_result[i-1] == "H") {
    coin_result[i] <- sample(c("H", "T"), 1, prob = c(0.6, 0.4))
  } else {
    coin_result[i] <- sample(c("H", "T"), 1, prob = c(0.4, 0.6))
  }
}

#tidy up
my_data <- data.frame(student_id, coin_result)
my_data <- my_data[order(my_data$student_id),]

final <- my_data %>%
    group_by(student_id) %>%
    mutate(flip_number = row_number())
```

**My Question:** Using this data, I want to perform the following procedure:

- Step 1: Randomly sample (with replacement) 100 student id's from `final` (e.g. resample_id_1 = student_1, resample_id_2 = student_54,resample_id_3 =  student_23, resample_id_4 = student_54, etc. )
- Step 2: For each resample_id, select all rows of data for that student - if this student appears multiple times, this student's data will also appear multiple times
- Step 3: For each resample_id, count the number of times the coin went from HH, HT, TH, and TT (make sure not to count a transition occurring between the last row of resample_id_n and resample_id_n+1) . Store these results.
- Step 4: Repeat Step 1 - Step 3 many times

This is my attempt at doing this:

```
set.seed(123) 
ids <- 1:100 

library(dplyr)

results <- list()

for (j in 1:100) {
  selected_ids <- sample(ids, 100, replace = TRUE)
  
  resampled_data <- data.frame()
  
  for (i in 1:length(selected_ids)) {
    current_id <- selected_ids[i]
    current_data <- final %>% filter(student_id == current_id)
    current_data$resampled_id <- i
    resampled_data <- rbind(resampled_data, current_data)
  }
  
  current_result <- resampled_data %>%
    group_by(resampled_id) %>%
    summarize(Sequence = str_c(coin_result, lead(coin_result)), .groups = 'drop') %>%
    filter(!is.na(Sequence)) %>%
    count(Sequence)
  
  results[[j]] <- current_result
}
```

**My Question:** Apart from taking a long time to run, I am not sure if I am doing this correctly. I am worried that within a given iteration, if the same student appears 3 times in the re-sampled dataset, the last transition from the first time will "leak" into the the first transition from the second time and thus compromise the results.

Thanks!

**Note: Optional Code to Visualize the Results**

```
final_result <- data.frame(iteration = 1:100, HH = numeric(100), HT = numeric(100), TH = numeric(100), TT = numeric(100))

for (i in 1:100) {
  current_result <- results[[i]]
  total_count <- sum(current_result$n)
  final_result$HH[i] <- current_result$n[current_result$Sequence == "HH"] / total_count
  final_result$HT[i] <- current_result$n[current_result$Sequence == "HT"] / total_count
  final_result$TH[i] <- current_result$n[current_result$Sequence == "TH"] / total_count
  final_result$TT[i] <- current_result$n[current_result$Sequence == "TT"] / total_count
}

library(ggplot2)

final_result_long <- final_result %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(HH, HT, TH, TT), names_to = "Sequence", values_to = "Probability")

ggplot(final_result_long, aes(x = iteration, y = Probability, color = Sequence)) +
  geom_line()
```

Comment: Can you clarify where in the code you think there may be an issue? I don't understand this part of your question: "The last transition from the first time will "leak" into the the first transition from the second time and thus compromise the results"

Comment: @ mfg3zo: thank you for your reply! I included some some code in the "optional selection" which visualizes the results. If you run the code to make the graph, shouldn't the lines for HH and TT be almost identical .... and shouldn't the lines of TH and HT be almost identical? Yet in my graph, this clearly not the case?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the `tidyverse`, you might as well make use of its capabilities rather than doing this with `for` loops. Here is one option that (I think) recreates what you are trying to do...

```
my_data <- tibble(student_id = sort(sample(ids, 100000, replace = TRUE))) %>% 
  group_by(student_id) %>% 
  mutate(coin_result = c(sample(c(0, 1), 1),        #easier with 0/1 than H/T
                         sample(c(0, 1), n() - 1,   #0 = "same", 1 = "different"
                                prob = c(0.6, 0.4), replace = TRUE)),
         coin_result = c("H", "T")[1+ cumsum(coin_result) %% 2], #convert to H/T
         Sequence = paste0(lag(coin_result), coin_result))       #create sequences

results <- tibble(iteration = 1:100) %>% 
  mutate(selected_ids = map(iteration, ~sample(ids, 100, replace = TRUE)),
         id_no = map(iteration, ~1:100)) %>% #to keep track of repeat-sampled ids
  unnest(c(selected_ids, id_no)) %>% 
  left_join(my_data %>% select(selected_ids = student_id, Sequence), 
            relationship = "many-to-many") %>%    
  count(iteration, id_no, Sequence) %>% 
  filter(nchar(Sequence) == 2) %>%        #remove first element of sequence NAH/NAT
  group_by(iteration, Sequence) %>% 
  summarise(n = sum(n)) %>%               #still grouped by iteration
  mutate(Probability = n / sum(n))
  
ggplot(results, aes(x = iteration, y = Probability, color = Sequence)) +
  geom_line()
```

Answer (score 1):

A clean and readable way of sampling students and associate their ids with data rows would be like this:

```
unique_ids <- unique(final$student_id)
sample_ids <- sample(unique_ids, size = 100, replace = TRUE)

unique_ids <- unique(final$student_id)
sample_ids <- sample(unique_ids, size = 100, replace = TRUE)

student_data <- lapply(sample_ids, function(id) {
  final %>% filter(student_id == id)
})
```

As a result You get a list of data.frames.

The further part of Your question is not clear for me. What do You mean by "the coin went from HH, HT, TH, and TT (make sure not to count a transition occurring between the last row of resample_id_n and resample_id_n+1)"? Do You want to count all sequences where two first flips present these patterns?